# How can I bind a selected data row from a json file to an input field(text)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, data-binding, binding

I need to bind a single data(json) row to an input field onclick event.

```
<script>
                              var Jsonstr = <?php echo $resObjstr; ?>;
                              for (var key in Jsonstr) {
                                  if (Jsonstr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                    //console.log(Jsonstr[key]["tile_name"] + ", " + Jsonstr[key]["id"]);
                                    $('.rowP1').append("<tr><td>"+Jsonstr[key]['id']+"</td><td><a href='#' title='"+Jsonstr[key]['tile_name']+"' id='"+Jsonstr[key]['id']+"' onClick='getDetails("+Jsonstr[key]['id']+",modifytile)'>"+Jsonstr[key]['tile_name']+"</a></td><td>"+Jsonstr[key]['detail']+"</td><td><img src='wp-content/themes/orchid-new/assets/img/"+Jsonstr[key]['image']+"' width='138' height='79' style='border:1px solid #999999;'/></td><td class='showprov' data-prov=''>"+Jsonstr[key]['providers']+"</td><td>"+Jsonstr[key]['states']+"</td><td>"+Jsonstr[key]['occurring']+"</td><td><button type='button' class='delTile' onclick='DelTiles("+Jsonstr[key]['id']+");'><i class='material-icons'>delete_forever</i></button></td></tr>");
                                  }
                              }
                          </script>
<a href="#"onclick='getDetails(tileid);'>Link</a>
function getDetails(tileid){
    console.log(tileid);
    if (tileid != null || tileid !=''){
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#modifytile"]').tab('show');

        var jsondata = <?php echo $resObjstr; ?>;
        for (key in jsondata) {
            if (jsondata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    $.each(jsondata[key], function (index, val) {
                        var txt = $('#tile_name').eq(index).val(val);
                        $('#tile_name').eq(index).val(val);
                        console.log(txt);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead it displays the very last row from the json string. As you can see from the sample image the json data is rendering just fine. [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDmMF.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, `break` the loop then;

```
for (key in jsondata) {
    if (jsondata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            $.each(jsondata[key], function (index, val) {
                var txt = $('#tile_name').eq(index).val(val);
                $('#tile_name').eq(index).val(val);
                console.log(txt);
                return false;
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: by breaking the loop does not mean I will get the correct selected record, which is my issue. I want to be able to click on the link of the looped json string and populated the form fields to modify the record via ajax post to the DB.

Comment: "tileid" where is it come from ?

Answer (score 0):

use console.log(jsondata) after declaring the variable to see how you get the variable $resObjstr and on that you know how to parse the json to be accessible by javascript

Comment: I already know what the jsondata string is. it is coming from a wordpress table. PHP code 

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_tiles', OBJECT );
$resObj = json_encode($results);
$resObjstr =  (string)$resObj;

Comment: Can you put the resulting json?

Comment: When you loop through the json you must compare the actual row with the id that you need so that at that moment select the appropriate row

Comment: oh that file has lots of info, but it has nothing to do with the Json file as I'm currently populating a table with the json data. See updated code plus image.

Comment: um...how's that supposed to help? I can display the records without a problem. The issue is clicking on the link for a row and have it populate the form to modify the selected record.

Comment: that helps me understand more, about what you need

Comment: if you look at the code on the post you  can see how I'm parsing the table rows.